# php, mysql if $a is in database

Tags: php, mysql, sql, arrays, foreach

How to print all times, but that one whitch is in datbase with the same name (value)
that should be printed   has text attached, or value is bolded?
Sorry for my bad english ;D

Here are the values

```
$a = '9.00';
$b = '10.00';
$c = '11.00';
$d = '12.00';
$e = '13.00';
$f = '14.00';
$g = '15.00';
$h = '16.00';
$i = '17.00';
$j = '18.00';

$date = '5/21/2012';
$q = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM times WHERE date='$date'");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($q)){
$time = $row['time'];
....

}
```

how to make it? with arrays? or foreach... HELP, please ;D

outcome would be:

`9.00 - AVAIBLE` -> this one is not in db
`10.00 - NOT AVAIBLE` -> this one is in database
`11.00 - NOT AVAIBLE` -> this one is in database
`12.00 - NOT AVAIBLE` -> this one is in database
.....

Comment: To me it's not clear what you mean. Can you give some examples of input vs output?

Comment: Try to write your question more clear ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand, you want to print all the times `$a..$j` but if they occur in your query result to bold them or identify them.

```
// Store all times in an array rather than variables...
$times = array('9.00','10.00','11.00','12.00','13.00','14.00','15.00','16.00','17.00','18.00');

// Array to hold times from the database query
$dbtimes = array();

date = '5/21/2012';
$q = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM times WHERE date='$date'");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($q)){

  // Place database times onto the array
  $dbtimes[] = $row['time'];
}

// Iterate over all the times and if the same time occurs in the databse
// array list, output it with special marks as needed.
foreach ($times as $t) {
  if (in_array($t, dbtimes)) {
     // Print bolded time $t
     echo '<strong>$t</strong>';
  }
  else {
     // Print regular time $t
     echo $t;
  }
}
```

Note that `5/21/2012` is *not* a valid date format for MySQL datetime types (`2012-05-12` is).  Hopefully your column `date` is a proper datetime type and not a custom string like `5/21/2012`.  If it isn't, I recommend changing it to a proper datetime.

Answer (score 0):

```
// store all the times in an array
$mytimes = array('9.00', '10.00', ..., '18.00');

$date = '5/21/2012';
$q = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM times WHERE date='$date'");

while($row = mysql_retch_assoc($q){
    $time = $row['time'];

    // loop through the array, if the time matches the value in the database, 
    // make it bold
    foreach($mytimes as $timecheck){
        if($time == $timecheck){
            // make bold
            echo '<b>'.$timecheck.'</b><br>';
        }
        else{
            echo $timecheck.'<br>';
        }
    }
}
```